# Implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'

Tags: c#, filter, implicit

I have to deal to question: Filter all the Student in the list with Result is "Pass". But when I write a code like in the picture below, it always return wrong with caution like this: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'. Although I used Convert.ToBoolean(t.Result) but it can't work?

Help me!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add your code as text, not a picture. You are also saying `.Where(t => t.Result)`. But you haven't specified *what* you want it to do. Where the result equals *what*? In this case, you probably want `.Where(t => t.Result == "Pass")`

Comment: Instead of attaching it as image, could you please write your code in the question.

Comment: I downvoted this question because you should always supply code and error messages as text, not images (otherwise elements of your question can not be searched). Edit your question. Add the code, then I can remove my DV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Filter all the Student in the list with Result is "Pass" you need to add the condition as:

```
lst.Where(t => t.Result=="Pass").ToList();
```

You can do the same with a Boolean property instead for this string, so the property definition will be like:

```
public bool  Result
{
    get { return Score > 25; }           
}
```

So the iterative condition for Filtering all the Student in the list with Result is "Pass"`(Score > 25)` will be

```
lst.Where(t => t.Result).ToList();
```

Comment: in fact you could just say `return Score > 25;`

Comment: @HariPrasad : yes absolutely; thank you i have updated the answer

Comment: Thank you! It's very helpful

Answer (score 4):

"True" and "False" are the only strings that can be converted to boolean using [`Convert.ToBoolean`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86hw82a3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Some options are:

- Change your method to return `true` or `false` as booleans instead of strings
- Change your method to return the strings "True" or "False" and call `Convert.ToString`
- Write  a wrapper method to convert "Pass" and "Fail" to `true` and `false`.
- Change your condition to `.Where(t => t.Result == "Pass")`

Comment: `Convert.ToBoolean` isn't case sensitive, so it can also accept "true" and "false".

Comment: Thank you! It's very helpful. Thanks